# How to create a tutorial overlay feature in a website?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a tutorial feature for my user on my website. I'm planning to create a dark overlay layer on the whole screen, and on a specific area, the background is completely transparent, so the user understand the area which the tutorial is talking about.

Here what I have done :

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>THIS IS CONTENT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

on CSS :

```
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.overlay > div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

  height: 30px;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

the `div` inside `.overlay` has no effect since the background of the `div` is ON TOP of the `.overlay`

Comment: So where's the problem ?

Comment: I cannot make the transparent part.

Comment: You can't make a parent of the background transparent, you'll have to apply a higher z-index to the element you want to appear on top.

Comment: Yeah, I figure it already. That's where I stuck. I need a work-around to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I think prevents your content `div` from being displayed under the overlay is that you haven't specified a `z-index` for that. If you specify one for the larger container `div` like so: `<div id="cont">` and give it a `z-index` smaller than that of the overlay (<9999) perhaps your problem will be solved.

UPDATE: I've read through your question again, and to solve your actual problem, you should make specific content and background `div`-s inside the master `overlay` container. It also seems to be important to add `position: absolute;` to the content div of the overlay.

UPDATE 2: To make the `#cont` stay visible as the overlay shows up, just add a greater `z-index` for that `div` than the one used by the `overlay`, and add a `position: absolute;` to it to make it specific.

Below is a working snippet.

```css
#cont {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9990;
}

#overlay-cont {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top :40px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 9990;
  display: block;
}

#overlay-bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  Width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 9980;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cont">
    <p>THIS IS CONTENT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div id="overlay-cont">The overlay content goes here.</div>
    <div id="overlay-bg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah, this is not what i meant. The "THIS IS CONTENT" must not be covered by the black background, its have to be completely transparent.